# How can we enable log compaction using spring cloud stream?

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

How to set log.cleanup.policy: compact using spring configuration

Answer (score 2):

This property is a Broker Config: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs. Therefore has to be configured on the broker side. There is nothing to do from the Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder perspective. It is just a client to the existing Apache Kafka broker.

If you talk about `KafkaEmbedded` from the Spring Kafka perspective, there are these options:

```
/**
 * Specify the properties to configure Kafka Broker before start, e.g.
 * {@code auto.create.topics.enable}, {@code transaction.state.log.replication.factor} etc.
 * @param brokerProperties the properties to use for configuring Kafka Broker(s).
 * @return this for chaining configuration
 * @see KafkaConfig
 */
public KafkaEmbedded brokerProperties(Map<String, String> brokerProperties) {
    this.brokerProperties.putAll(brokerProperties);
    return this;
}

/**
 * Specify a broker property.
 * @param property the property name.
 * @param value the value.
 * @return the {@link KafkaEmbedded}.
 * @since 2.1.4
 */
public KafkaEmbedded brokerProperty(String property, Object value) {
    this.brokerProperties.put(property, value);
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`log.cleanup.policy` is a broker configuration (in server.properties), not a client property.

To change the policy for a single topic

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic myTopic --config cleanup.policy=compact
```

or

```
kafka-configs --zookeeper localhost:2181 --entity-type=topics --entity-name=mytopic --alter --add-config cleanup.policy=compact
```

(since the first one is deprecated)

```
WARNING: Altering topic configuration from this script has been deprecated and may be removed in future releases.
     Going forward, please use kafka-configs.sh for this functionality
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating this answer based on Gary's and Artem's answers below to avoid any confusion.

You can pass any arbitrary kafka client configuration using the key `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration...`. However, since `log.cleanup.policy` is a broker level property, you cannot use it this way from the binder. You need to set it on the broker. Please see the answers below for more information.